# Filter JSON response on a jQuery ajax request, for XSS text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, xss

I am falling into a silly issue where the server is giving JSON response with XSS safe text added.

The server gives only 2 kinds of response:

1. HTML page with hidden input field that contains the value I want
2. JSON String with the value which can be preferably converted to JS
   Object.

The problem is, for preventing JavaScript XSS attacks, the JSON response is made like this:

```
while(1);{
    "name": {
        "abc": "123",
        ...
        }
    }
```

So this goes to `parseerror` in jQuery `ajax` method and therefore in the `error` callback.

How do I fix this?

Also, I tried putting a hook in the error function and change the JSON data:

```
error: function(jqXHR) {
    removeJSCode (jqXHR.responseText);
}

// ...

function removeJSCode(json) {
    .. Code to filter the response
}
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Why not just pass valid JSON and do proper XSS filtering on the server?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `$.ajax` has `dataFilter` property in its configuration. Pass it a function and it runs after jQuery receives ajax data, *but before* jQuery has a chance to touch it.

The function is provided the string response as first argument and data type as second argument. The second argument will depend if you passed `dataType` in the configuration.

There, you can use `.replace('while(1);','')` and return the string from the function for jQuery to parse.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType : 'json',
    dataFilter : function(response,type){
      //if not JSON, don't do anything with it
      if(type !== 'json') return response;
      //otherwise, replace and return
      return response.replace('while(1);','');
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Yup. I am doing the same thing in an error callback, since I did not know of the `dataFilter`. Which version of jQuery is supported for it? -asking since I am forced to use `1.4.2`

Comment: @OmShankar You can try putting it there, fire up a request and do some console.log or breakpoint on the function.

Comment: No. I said thanks for the `dataFilter`. I was trying to achieve the same thing in the error function, since I did not know about it. `dataFilter` worked.